# ¿Cuál es el método más óptimo para sustituir un dígito a un número por otro dígito?

Tags: java, array

Le pido al usuario un número, el dígito que quiere intercambiar y la posición que quiere que vaya he empleado bucles for multiplicando y dividiendo por 10 y no me salían las ideas ,ahora estoy probando con arrays y me da error al compilar seguramente la sintaxis no es la correcta, alguien me indica como debería resolver este problema ya no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PerezSuarezCristoRuben_Ejercicios_en_casa_1_04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el número que quiere arreglar:");
        int userNumber = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el dígito que quiere añadir: ");
        int userDigit = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca la posición en la que quiere que vaya el dígito:");
        int userPosition = sc.nextInt();

        int num[] = new int[userNum];

        num[userPosition] = num[userDigit];

        System.out.println("Aquí tiene su arreglo: " + num);

    }

}
```

Comment: _Me da error al compilar_: ¿cuál error? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles.

Comment: Estas poniendo int num[]=new int[userNum] pero userNum que valor tiene? lo otro es que un arreglo tiene valores predeterminados los cuales debes instanciar antes de preguntar el numero que quiere modificar

Answer (score 0):

El problema es poner el next int puede causar problemas. Prueba el código así

```
public class PerezSuarezCristoRuben_Ejercicios_en_casa_1_04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el número que quiere arreglar:");
        int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Introduzca el dígito que quiere añadir: ");
        int userDigit = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Introduzca la posición en la que quiere que vaya el dígito:");
        int userPosition = sc.nextInt();

        int num[] = new int[userNum];

        num[userPosition] = num[userDigit];

        System.out.println("Aquí tiene su array: " + num);

    }

}
```

Comment: Interesante voy a probarlo thanks.